# IIFE to be used to avoid name clashing?

Tags: javascript

```js
(function(){
  var a = b = 3;
})();

(function(){
  var a = b = 5;
})();


console.log(b)
console.log(a)
```

IIFE helps to avoid name clashing with other modules? I've tried the above code to understand the concept. Basically can I assume that the above two IIFE representing two different "module" and that variable `b` shouldn't be overriden? However as we can tell the value of `b` being overriden to 5 instead.

Another question is that, why is variable `a` be undefined in above case?
I thought essentially the code will be translated to below

```
var a = b = 3;

let b = 3;
let a = b;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
var a = b = 3;
```

first considers

```
b = 3
```

which assigns `3` to the (implicitly global) variable "b". This assignment expression evaluates to `3`, so

```
var a = b = 3;
```

then turns into

```
var a = 3;
```

The `var` before the `a` means that the variable name `a` is defined *only inside the containing function* - it doesn't leak out into the global scope. Had you used

```
a = b = 3;
```

then, like `b`, `a` would have been implicitly assigned to the global object as well.

You probably want to make sure each IIFE has a *separate binding* for `b`, which can be done by declaring `b` with `var` first:

```js
(function(){
  var b;
  var a = b = 3;
})();

(function(){
  var b;
  var a = b = 5;
})();
// neither a nor b are defined here

console.log(b)
console.log(a)
```

Best to always declare a variable name with `var` (or, even better, `const` or `let`) before you use it.

It would also be good to avoid evaluating an assignment as an expression, when possible, because it looks confusing:

```js
(function(){
  var b = 3;
  var a = b;
})();

(function(){
  var b = 3;
  var a = b;
})();
// neither a nor b are defined here

console.log(b)
console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 3):

`var a = b = 3;` is an anti-pattern for this very reason. When you do this `b` is never declared with `var`. It is equivalent to :

```
b = 3         // no var makes b global 
var a = b;    // var a is scoped to enclosing function
```

This puts `b` in the global namespace which is probably not what you wanted.

```js
function test(){
  var a = b = 3;  // b 'looks' like it will be function scoped...but
}

test()
console.log(b) // b is global even though defined in the function
```

Answer (score 0):

assigning a variable without `var` creates an "automatically global variable"
which is why a is undefined but b isn't